# How do you set the 'Edit Configuration' in IntellIJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After I deleted a file that I thought I didn't need, all of my java classes won't run and instead a window pops up asking me to edit configuration.

What should I do to make the java classes run again?

[image: Here is the current status of my screen]

Comment: You have to mark your "src" folder as source. Right click the "src" folder, choose "Mark Directory as" and mark it as "Sources Root".

Comment: Thanks! After marking the directory as you said, the classes are working normally now.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Exit IntelliJ
2. Delete .idea directory
3. Open the project in IntelliJ